How to remove subdivision surface artifacts?
Maybe this is a newbie question.
Bad artifacts appear at some corners when Bevel and Subdivision surface modifiers are used.
Please see the areas marked with yellow circle in the following screen capture.

This capture is for the edit mode. Light blue edges are beveled with weight 1.

I want clean, sharp corners.
I appreciate any help you can provide.
UPDATE: I added edges according to the answer to the question Problem using Bevel and Subdivision Workflow. Indeed the artifact is gone, but another (pinching?) artifact appeared.

Carefully adding edges to fine-tune the curves created by the subdivision surface modifier might be necessary.

